# Agregar fila a una tabla

Tags: jquery

Tengo un problema con una tabla, deseo agregar filas en una tabla con JQuery.
Al momento de agregar y eliminar las filas todo bien, pero al momento guardar estas filas en una base de datos se guardan todas en un único registro. 
Por ejemplo: Al momento de guardar 5 filas de productos, se guardan los 5 en un solo campo de la base de datos.

¿Me podrían ayudar por favor?

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#nuevalinea").click(function () {
            var clonarfila = $("#tablaresponsive").find("tbody tr:last").clone();
            $("table tbody").append(clonarfila);
        });

        $("#tablaresponsive").on('click', '.eliminalinea', function () {
            var numeroFilas = $("#tablaresponsive tr").length;
            if (numeroFilas > 2) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tablaresponsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <%--<th><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat"></th>--%>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad Canjes</th>
      <th>Factura</th>
      <th>Fecha Factura</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><%--<input type ="number" name="Producto[]" class="form-control">--%><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" type ="number" name="Producto[]" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
       <td>
         <input type ="number" name="Cantidad Canjes[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type ="number" name="Factura[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td><input type ="number" name="Fecha Factura[]" id="textboxfila"  class="form-control"></td>
 
        
      
        <td><button type="button" class="eliminalinea">eliminar</button></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>

    <tr>
     
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad Canjes</th>
      <th>Factura</th>
      <th>Fecha Factura</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" type ="number" name="Producto[]" class="form-control" runat="server">

           </asp:TextBox></td>
       <td>
         <input type ="number" name="Cantidad Canjes[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type ="number" name="Factura[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td><input type ="number" name="Fecha Factura[]" id="textboxfila"  class="form-control"></td>
 
        
      
        <td><button type="button" class="eliminalinea">eliminar</button></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="nuevalinea" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> FILA</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el codigo con el que obtienes los datos de las filas y la consulta para que podamos ayudar

Comment: Supongo que será una errata al haber copiado un cacho de código pero, la segunda tabla tiene dos errores en el html: Cierras la etiqueta `table` pero nunca llegas a abrirla.  Lo mismo te pasa con el `thead` que abres a continuación.